# How to copy same portion of data from 232 sheets to table?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to copy a set of data from 232 consecutive spreadsheets and then dump into a master spreadsheet.

I seem to be doing something wrong with activating the sheets.

```vb
Sub mcrExtractData()
    
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim introw As Integer
    
    For i = 1 To 10

        For introw = 1 To 10
    
            Sheets("Sheet & i").Select   Range("B3:B5").Select
            Selection.Copy
            Sheets("Sheet500").Select
            Range("A & introw").Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
              :=False, Transpose:=True
    
            Sheets("Sheet & i").Select
            Range("Q7:Q12").Select
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            Selection.Copy
            Sheets("Sheet500").Select
            Range("A & introw").Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
              :=False, Transpose:=True
    
        Next introw
    
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: You are copying 9 values. Do you want to paste them from columns `A` to column `I` in the first available row in `Sheet500`? Better share the exact range for each worksheet to be copied.

Comment: Do we know how many rows or columns are on each spreadsheet? Does each spreadsheet start in cell "A1", or does that vary? Does every cell in every tab have a value, or could some of them be empty?

Comment: `Sheets("Sheet & i")` and `Range("A & introw")` makes no sense. VBA is searching for a worksheet/cell named **exactly** like that. I think you should use `Sheets("Sheet " & i)` and `Range("A" & introw)` Notice I changed the position of the `"`

Answer (score 0):

### Copy Ranges From Multiple Worksheets

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub mcrExtractData()
    
    Const tgtName As String = "Sheet500"
    Const tgtFirst As String = "A2"
    Const genName As String = "Sheet"
    Const NumberOfWorksheets As Long = 232

    ' Define workbook.
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    ' Define Source Array ('Source').
    Dim Source As Variant
    ReDim Source(1 To NumberOfWorksheets, 1 To 2)
    
    ' Declare additional variables before loop.
    Dim ws As Worksheet ' Current Source Worksheet,
                        ' Target Worksheet.
    Dim i As Long       ' Current Worksheet Index,
                        ' Current Source Array Row,
                        ' Current Target Array Row.
    
    ' Write values from Source Worksheets to arrays of Source Array.
    For i = 1 To NumberOfWorksheets
        Set ws = wb.Worksheets(genName & i)
        Source(i, 1) = ws.Range("B3:B5").Value
        Source(i, 2) = ws.Range("Q7:Q12").Value
    Next i
    
    ' Define Target Array ('Target').
    Dim Target As Variant
    ReDim Target(1 To NumberOfWorksheets, 1 To 9)
    
    ' Declare additional variables before loop.
    Dim j As Long ' Current Target Array Column.
    
    ' Write values from arrays of Source Array to Target Array.
    For i = 1 To NumberOfWorksheets
        For j = 1 To 3
            Target(i, j) = Source(i, 1)(j, 1)
        Next j
        For j = 4 To 9
            Target(i, j) = Source(i, 2)(j - 3, 1)
        Next j
    Next i
    
    ' Define Target Worksheet ('ws').
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets(tgtName)
    ' Write values from Target Array to Target Range.
    ws.Range(tgtFirst).Resize(NumberOfWorksheets, 9).Value = Target
    
End Sub
```